# What is `mode` argument of `trace_add` method in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/) states:
`Mode: It is one of “array”, “read”, “write”, “unset”, or a list or tuple of such strings.` but I'm not sure I understand what it means.

I'm using `trace_add` to call a function whenever my object `tk.StringVar` changes value and I'm using the mode `write` without really understanding why.

EDIT: what I find online is only about the deprecated method `trace`; nothing about the method `trace_add`.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.html#M14) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the value "write" means you want the callback to be called whenever the variable is written (ie: changed; when the `set` method is called).

Using the value "read" means you want the callback to be called whenever the variable is read (ie: the `get` method is called).

Using the value "unset" means you want the callback to be called whenever the variable is unset. In the case of tkinter, this happens when the variable is deleted.

The canonical tcl documentation for "array" says: *"Invoke commandPrefix whenever the variable is accessed or modified via the array command"*. Tkinter doesn't directly give access to tcl's `array` command, so this one isn't very useful in tkinter.